# Integrity Check Error for Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed new version of Eclipse (Luna).
Then i installed 'My Eclipse Workbench' plugin from Eclipse Market.

When i tried to restart Eclipse giving the following error.

Error:

```
Security Alert : Integrity Check Error
This Product did not pass the MyEclipse integrity check. This security check is prerequisite for launch for MyEclipse. Please reinstall MyEclise and try again.

Specific Error: The signature chain is used to sign on MyEclipse is either not valid or does not belongs to Genuitec. MyEclipse features will not start with unsigned installation. Reason: No trusted certificate chain is used for signing.
```

Comment: You need to buy digital signature file from `Genuitec` to run MyEclipse. That's what you error says.

Comment: What platform is this (Mac, Linux, Unix, Windows)?

Comment: This error is occuring on Windows

Answer (score -1):

Delete `C:\Users\{*username*}\.myeclipse`   It worked for me.